# Infinitely many integer triples $(x, y, z)$ satisfying $x^2 + 2y^2 = 3z^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

My book mentions a proof involving a 1:1 correspondence with rational slopes through the point $(1, 1)$, I guess for every value of $z$. I'm interested in this approach but I don't know how to make it work.

Otherwise, how would I go about proving this?

Comment: I can prove that there exist infinitely many solutions to $x^2 + 2y^2 = 3z$ but not $3z^2$.
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{R}, \ (n + 1)^2 + (n^3 + n^2)^2 + 2(n^2 + n)^2 = (n^3 + n^2 + n + 1)^2$$ Therefore, we must show that $$3\mid (n^3 + n^2 + n + 1)^2 - (n + 1)^2 = \big((n^3 + n^2 + 2(n + 1)\big)(n^3 + n^2)$$

Comment: Now attempt to prove by induction that $3\mid n^3 + n^2 + 2(n + 1)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Simply suppose that $$\begin{align} 3\mid (n + 1)^3 + (n + 1)^2 + 2(n + 2) &= n^3 + 1 + 3n(n + 1) + n^2 + 1 + 2n + 2(n + 2) \\ \Leftrightarrow 3&\mid n^3 + n^2 + 2(2n + 3) \\ \Leftrightarrow 3&\mid n^3 + n^2 + 4n \end{align}$$

Comment: We can also prove by induction that $3\mid n^3 + 2n$ follows that $3\mid n^2 + 2n = (n + 1)^2 - 1$.

Thus, $x^2 + 2y^2 = 3z^2$ has infinitely many solutions $(x, y, z)$ over the integers. To make things simple, you can find $z$ iff (if and only if) $$\begin{align} x &= n^3 + n^2 \\ y &= n^2 + n \\ 3&\mid (n + 1)^2 - 1\end{align}$$
Maybe this might help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We may find all the rational points on $X^2+2Y^2=3$ by just considering that $(1,1)$ is one of them. Let us consider a line through $(1,1)$ with rational slope $m$ and its second intersection with the given ellipse: by Vieta's theorem, it is a rational point. Namely it is

$$ (X,Y) = \left(\frac{2m^2-4m-1}{2m^2+1},-\frac{2m^2+2m-1}{2m^2+1}\right) $$
and this gives a parametrization of all the rational points on our ellipse, with the only exception of $(X,Y)=(1,-1)$. By setting $m=\frac{p}{q}$ we may easily derive the identity

$$(2p^2-4pq-q^2)^2+ 2(2p^2+2pq-q^2) = 3(2p^2+q^2)^2 $$
proving the claim about the existence of infinite *primitive* solutions.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks.

Comment: really interesting ! +1

Comment: Fixed a small slip.

Answer (score 1):

If $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is a solution to this problem, then is also $x=x_ot$, $y=y_ot$ and $z=z_ot$ for each integer $t$. So you have to find this one solution $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and this is not difficult to do, since $(1,1,1)$ will do.

Comment: Oh yeah. Can't believe I didn't notice. Does this account for all the solutions, though?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm thinking about it.

Comment: unfortunately not, it does account for all the solutions: it only tells that the problem reduces to find the rational solutions $x/z,\;y/z$